# Normalizing an image in R using mean and standard deviation

Tags: python, r, image, tensorflow, normalize

Noob machine learner here!

I am attempting to normalize images in `R`, as I plan to submit them to be classified in the *Machine learning for wildlife image classification* (`MLWIC`) package in R.

The authors of the package mention that before images are classified, they should be resized to 256 x 256 pixels (easy enough) and then normalized. They cite using methods available in this appendix ([Norouzzadeh et al 2018](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/suppl/2018/06/04/1719367115.DCSupplemental/pnas.1719367115.sapp.pdf), [code here](https://github.com/Evolving-AI-Lab/deep_learning_for_camera_trap_images/))).

In brief, the normalization procedure is carried out using a python command that, for each color channel in the image, "Subtracts off the mean and divides by the variance of the pixels".

The documentation for the python function they used,  `tf.image.per_image_standardization()` states:

> Linearly scales image to have zero mean and unit variance.
>   This op computes (x - mean) / adjusted_stddev, where mean is the average of all values in image, and adjusted_stddev = max(stddev, 1.0/sqrt(image.NumElements())).

If I am trying to replicate this process in `R`. However, when I attempt to re-write the `tf.image.per_image_standardization()` function in R, it changes the image from having a range of [0,1] in each color channel to a range that is, for example, -1.85 to 1.85. The resulting image does not look like the saturated image displayed in the appendix, linked to above.

Here's the original image:

[image: animal_original]

Here's the processed image as it is supposed to look:

[image]

The code I've tried:

```
library(imager)
library(tidyverse)
ante <- load.image("original.jpg")
plot(ante)
normalize <- function(x) (x - mean(x))/sd(x)
ante %>% 
  imsplit("c") %>% 
  modify_at(1, normalize) %>% 
  modify_at(2, normalize) %>% 
  modify_at(3, normalize) %>% 
  imappend("c") %>% 
  plot()
```

I also tried the following, the resulting image looks more saturated than the original, but it does not use the mean or sd...

```
library(magick)
process_image <- function(image.path, new.image.path){
  tryCatch(
    {
      image_write(image_equalize(image_scale(image_read(image.path),"256x256!")), path = new.image.path)
      return(substr(image.path, nchar(image.path) - 2, nchar(image.path)))
    },
    error = function(e)  
    {
      return(NA)
    }
  )
}
process_image("original.jpg", "processed.jpg")
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: I may have missed something but why is the question tagged python?

Comment: Thanks Jacques, `tensorflow` is a `python` library, so I want python users to see this.